# Eclipse Bug on My PC only

Tags: java, swing, driver, java-2d

The code works perfectly on all of the other pc's that I have used before, and after, but for some reasons when I run it on my computer it has an odd bug.

When I click on a square and then a circle then the new colour of the square that I just clicked on will become the colour of the background to the circle that I clicked on, not the fill of the circle but the actual background.

Also when a circle is clicked on for the first time then there is an outline of a blue circle to the right of the circle that I clicked on.

Please I need help so that I can code on my computer, and am able to do my coursework.
I have switched between computers that use 1.6 and 1.7 and changed them so that they work, and all was okay. So from what i have seen it is just my pc, I have updated all of the java programs that I can (JDK, the drivers for my graphics card, eclipse) I just cant seem to figure it out.

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
    import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
    import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
    import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
    import java.awt.geom.RectangularShape;
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;
    import java.util.Random;

    import javax.swing.*;

    public class Part2 extends JFrame {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Part2 window = new Part2("Shape Colour");
            window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        }

        public Part2(String title) {
            super(title);

            //adds the circle and square objects to the new Panel
            JPanel all = new JPanel();
            this.setContentPane(all);
            this.setSize(900, 200);
            this.setResizable(true);
            all.setLayout(new GridLayout());
            all.add(new Circle());
            all.add(new Rectangle());
            all.add(new Circle());
            all.add(new Rectangle());
            all.add(new Circle());        

            setVisible(true);
        }

        abstract class shape extends JPanel {
            Random random = new Random();
            RectangularShape shape;
            Color color;

            //creates a shape of random "colour" (notice the "u"), and adds a MouseListener
            public shape() {
                super();
                //this.setSize();
                randomColor();
                this.addMouseListener(new ShapeListener(this));
            }        

            //Decided how to paint the shape, and fill it with one colour
            //names each shape "thing"
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponents(g);
                Graphics2D thing = (Graphics2D) g;
                thing.setColor(color);
                thing.fill(shape);
            }        

            //makes a random colour form all possible combinations of colour
            private void randomColor() {
                this.color = new Color(random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(256),random.nextInt(256));
            }

            class ShapeListener implements MouseListener {        

                JPanel ShapePanel;
                int mouseX;
                int mouseY;

                //shapePanel constructor
                public ShapeListener(JPanel shapePanel) {
                    this.ShapePanel = shapePanel;
                }        

                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    //gets the mouse coordinates 
                    mouseX = e.getX();
                    mouseY = e.getY();
                    //if you click within the area of the shape that is at those coordinates then it will repaint, a random colour
                    if (shape.contains(mouseX, mouseY)) {
                    randomColor();
                ShapePanel.repaint();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //method for creating a circle
        class Circle extends shape {
            public Circle() {
                super();
                this.shape = new Ellipse2D.Double(10, 10, 150, 150);
            }
        }

        //and a square
        class Rectangle extends shape {
            public Rectangle() {
                super();
                this.shape = new Rectangle2D.Double(10, 10, 150, 150);
            }        

        }
   }
```

Comment: Possibly unrelated, but you have a typo in `paintComponent()`. The `super.paintComponents(g)` should be `super.paintComponent(g)`, without the last **s**.

Comment: I can't reproduce the bug, and it's a little bit hard to see what you are speaking about, can you take a screenshot of the bug an add it to the question ?

Comment: Could it be that its related to the theme your using?

Comment: Where is [`SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)?

Comment: I would also check if you have the latest graphics driver installed.

Comment: thank you guys for all your help, i unistalled the drivers, and deleted all of the java that was on my pc, only to find that it was a windows 8/swing bug. in the constructor for shape i needed to "this.setOpaque(false);".